# Перевести sql запросы с PostgreSql в MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется файл с расширением sql содержащий запросы для создания и наполнения БД на PostgreSql. Необходимо получить другой файл с расширением sql содержащий те же запросы, но предназначенные для MySql. В исходном файле более 2.000.000 строк.

Пожалуйста подскажите - существует ли какой-нибудь способ быстро это сделать?

Comment: попытаться выполнить, посмотреть какие ошибки возникают и сделать на любом языке скрипт который их переделает. Вообще синтаксис почти одинаковый. разница может заключаться в типах данных и возможно в формате дат

Comment: В общем случае самый быстрый вариант - восстановить БД из дампа в Postgres, после чего выгрузить в формате, пригодном для быстрой загрузки именно в MySQL.

Comment: Akina - к сожалению сама postgres не установлена и по определенным причинам нельзя её установить.

Comment: Mike - я просмотрел начало файла - присутствует много специфических для postgress настроек. Моежете посоветовать какой-нибудь конвертер?